# Is it good to choose IBM Bluemix to deploy a Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, server, ibm-cloud

I am starting a new project and wanted to know that is `IBM Bluemix` a right choice for deploying a `Wordpress` websites? I want to cater large audience with the website and it will be a content heavy website. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I created a wordpress blog site just in minute and it worked very well. But if you have a trial account , also you have limited sources and services area. That's why , it may be created a problem for you. I suggest you to try creating and then analyze it.